# generated StoredProcedures.vb class is empty

Tags: mysql, subsonic

i've added to my MySQL database, 2 stored procedures, then generated data access classes using the Subsonic Tool in visual studio... i notice that the StoredProcedures.cs class is empty.. why is that? and what do i do now? how will i use my stored procedures i my application?

im using subsonic 2.1 and mysql administrator 5.0..

please.. i need your help.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and just as what i have previously read, it has to do with compatibity issues..
previously, i was using subsonic 2.1 and mysql 5.5 so i think their versions are not compatible.. i downgraded mine to subsonic 2.0 and mysql 5.0 instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be getting the same problem..
please see my post for suggestions (as of yet I've not fixed my problem yet)

[Subsonic, setting useSPs="true" doesn't seem to work. SPs aren't being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253828/subsonic-setting-usespstrue-doesnt-seem-to-work-sps-arent-being-generated)